# Material-ui jss перебивает стили бандла

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

На каждой странице есть два бандла - header с меню и сам контент. Использую stylesprovider injectfirst чтобы jss стили не перебивали мои.
Но jss одного бандла импортится ниже второго и перебивает его стили, едет верстка. Уже замучился в попытках решить эту проблему.[image: как это выглядит в верстке]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `material-ui` есть способ изменить порядок внедрения стилей. Нужно обернуть ваш код в `StyleProvider` с атрибутом `injectFirst`, и тогда они будут внедряться перед вашими стилями а не после них:

```
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';

<StylesProvider injectFirst>
  {/* Здесь ваш код... */}
</StylesProvider>
```